# display most recent query result

Tags: php

i have a query that i use to count the number of rows as a result, but i would also like to print out the most recent row of that query, in a view, but only that recent query instead of the whole array

basically i use this query, then run a count to display the amount of rows which is a count i display, but i also want to display the latest date, location, and code, it can only get it to display all

Comment: Please show your query. Are you in mysql?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

2 options...

```
Select * from table order by primary_key desc;
```

count the results and print the first (most recent) row

or run two separate queries...

```
select count(primary_key) as num_rows from table;
select * from table order by primary_key desc limit 1;
```

Comment: how do you print most recent row